# How to allow GET request on IIS when JsonRequestBehavior is set to AllowGet

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have asp.net mvc web application and app working on localhost fine, but after deploy on IIS server Json Get requests are blocked. I have JsonRequestBehavior set to AllowGet. I allow requests on IIS to all http requests and still getting this error:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet."

```
 using (cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sda.Fill(dt1);
                    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                    Dictionary<string, object> row;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dt1.Columns)
                        {
                            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                    return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
```

Are there any settings on IIS for filtering request?

EDIT:

After adding GET Verb to IIS Settings i got new error:

> System.ArgumentException: RecursionLimit exceeded.

Comment: Can you post the part of code, where you're returning result to view?

Comment: I use result for javascript graph. " $.get('@Url.Action("Chart_Data_withoutParams", "Graf")'," This is get action

Comment: Sorry I can't see attached images, that's why I'm asking to post controller code here.

Comment: i updated question with controller code :)

Comment: Try to return your `row` at the end of method, outside of `using`. Maybe some exception is occurring.

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: Can you post your whole method, also debug and check for any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it from this link https://www.compilemode.com/2015/10/request-has-been-blocked-In-mvc-json-result.html

I cant be clear about the answer as I cant see all your code

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    List<string> a = new List<string>();
    a.Add("A");

    return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```